# Identify Sublime Text 3 snippet source

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

Does anyone know how I can identify where a Sublime Text 3 code snippet is coming from? There's one for Rails that I thought was coming from a certain package. I've uninstalled said package but the snippet is still available for use. It's driving me nuts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl + Backtick</kbd> to open the console, paste the following code, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
sublime.active_window().new_file().run_command( "append", { "characters": "\n".join( sorted( sublime.find_resources( "*.sublime-snippet" ) ) ) } )
```

---

A list of all installed snippets will open in a new tab.  You can then search for the snippet you want to remove.

Snippets are shown with their full paths, so you will know which plugin directories they are located in.

---

I recommend using [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to open the snippet and comment out the contents, rather than deleting the snippet file.

This will effectively remove the snippet from the auto-complete list, maintain the original copy of the snippet within the package, and prevent a plugin update from replacing the deleted snippet file.

---

[image: Demo]

Comment: It appears the snippet in question is in a Rails package that I didn't install. Presume it must be part of the default Sublime packages. I'll look into how to remove them as the snippet is no longer relevant in Rails 4

Comment: Sorry, there's no need to look into how to remove them, you've given clear instructions above. Thanks a again