# sublime-text 3, where can i find installed themes

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, sidebar

I ve installed pretty many themes in my ST3. The thing i want to be done is to use these themes not only for main pane, but also for the side bar and icons. As far as I know - not every theme support side bar and icons. but for instance Seti does, Solarized does. That is what ive done to setup Seti.

```
"Seti_folder_icons": true,
"color_scheme": "Packages/Seti_UX/Seti.tmTheme",
"theme": "Seti.sublime-theme"
```

But now i want to change Seti to Solarized Dark/Light, Abyss, whatever. but i have no idea where their tm.Theme and .sublime-theme files are located and how to name themes here :

```
"????_folder_icons": true,
"color_scheme": "?????.tmTheme",
"theme": "????.sublime-theme"
```

i tried solarized-light and solarized_light, nothing worked. how can i know how to write proper names of themes ? and i dont know how to set up icons, Seti_folder_icons didnt work and others too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### See:

## [Identify Sublime Text 3 snippet source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033039/identify-sublime-text-3-snippet-source/37033619#37033619)

---

You can use that approach to find any type of SublimeText resource.

For example, the following code will find all `tmTheme` files:

```
sublime.active_window().new_file().run_command( "append", { "characters": "\n".join( sorted( sublime.find_resources( "*.tmTheme" ) ) ) } )
```

Comment: so there s not just a one or two folders where all themes are based? and i still have no idea how to name themes in config file

Comment: Nope.  Pretty much all of SublimeText's resources can be stored arbitrarily within packages.  You can move ( *some* ) files around and create your own structure if you want.  I personally have a few for core resources like: `Packages/[ Color Schemes ]`, `Packages/[ Macros ]`, `Packages/[ Snippets ]`, etc.

Comment: Also, you should edit this question down to the primary component asked in the title - which is where to find installed themes.  The other half about setting up a custom `sublime-theme` file should be asked as a separate question.  [**Read This**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and check out the links @ the bottom.  It might keep you from getting the downvote hammer dropped on you ( *the SO crew can be pretty salty sometimes lol*... )